# Code re-usability (inheritance) in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, inheritance

I want to design two `reactjs` classes. Most of the code contained in the two classes is the same. An example is shown in the following code snippet. As indicated using comments, most of the handler methods share the same logic and only a few handlers differ between the two classes `Items` and `Clients`.

```
class Items/Clients extends Component {
 state = {
   currInput: {
     // different for Items and Clients
   },
   data: [],
   formModalOpen: false,
   editMode: false
 };
 
 formModalOpenHandler = () => {
  // same logic for both clients and items
 };
 
 formModalCloseHandler = () => {
   this.setState({
     formModalOpen: false,
     currInput: {
      // different for Items and Clients
     },
     editMode: false
   });
 };
 
 inputChangeHandler = event => {
   // same logic for both clients and items
 
 };
 submitHandler = operation => {
   // same logic for both clients and items
 
 };
 deleteItem = (e, rowData) => {
   // same logic for both clients and items
 
 };
 
 editItemActionHandler = (e, rowData) => {
   // same logic for both clients and items
 
 };
 
 render() {
   let func;
   func = this.state.editMode
     ? () => this.submitHandler("edit")
     : () => this.submitHandler("save");
 
   return (
     <div>
       <Button
         onClick={this.formModalOpenHandler}
     >
         Create New Item / Create New Client
       </Button>
       <div >
         <MaterialTable
           columns={// different for clients and items}
           actions={// same for both clients and items}
           data={this.state.data}
           title="Items" / “Clients”
         />
       </div>
       <Modal
         open={this.state.formModalOpen}
         onClose={this.formModalCloseHandler}
        
       >
         <div>
        // different for clients and items 
           //for items
           <ItemForm
             inputChangeHandler={this.inputChangeHandler}
             value={{ ...this.state.currInput }}
             submitHandler={func}
           />
          //for clients
         <ClientForm
             value={this.state.currInput}
             inputChangeHandler={this.inputChangeHandler}
             submitHandler={func}
           />
 
         </div>
       </Modal>
     </div>
   );
 }
}
 
export default Items/Clients;
```

How can I reuse the code common to both classes? This will facilitate code re-usage reducing the redundancy for better debugging in the future.

I am looking for something similar to inheritance in `C++` but to the best of my knowledge reactjs does not support C++ kind inheritance.

Comment: Javascript classes *can* inherit from other classes, but React prefers [Composition over Inheritance](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html). For these situations I think most would factor the common code/logic into importable components and/or utility functions. Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code examples of the two class-based components you want to do some refactoring of? [What about inheritance?](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html#so-what-about-inheritance)

Answer (score 0):

The concept of inheritance in ReactJS and VueJS is roughly reversed, meaning you do not attach parent code in children using inheritance but rather push in child code into a parent.

So what you can maybe do is to push all this common code into another ReactJS component and importing them both into your two other parent components that build over it.

--EDIT--
The reversed concept of inheritance in ReactJS and VueJS is called Composition as mentioned by [Drew Reese](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8690857/drew-reese) in the comments.